# OrientDB in Azure

Tags: orientdb

We would like to use OrientDB Graph in an Azure environment. Does anybody has experience using it? We also would like to know if high availability from OrientDB is required under Azure cloud? Azure already offers high availability for Azure storage, Azure Drive and SQL. I understand that they have replications and load balancing built in.

This is super important because we prefer not to get into the business of replications and infrastructure management.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you can spin up 2 or more machines and install OrientDB on them, then configure them together as a distributed cluster. However I haven't been able to find any way that is simpler, easier to do. I am interested in this topic too.

Answer (score 0):

Azure does have features such as geo-replication, which is protects your data against a major data-center incident but doesn't provide any performance benefit and will not make it highly available.

Although pretty reliable, occasionally Microsoft will reboot servers for updates, so to protect against downtime you can use affinity groups so that, of your 2 or more servers, one will always be online. This however does need to be used in conjunction with database replication and ideally load balancing.

It's also worth noting that OrientDB recommends clusters have an odd number of servers as this can prevent conflicts when synchronising data after a communication issue between the servers.

Answer (score 0):

I am using it in amazon and I had to create a java project to monitor http requests inserts and queries. The queries are very fast but takes longer inserting data .

I recommend this type of graph database mode to decrease the time of the queries. Also if you have empty fields OrientDB manages very well compared to other databases .

If you need help with the java project can response to this post and I´ll help u.

I hope it helps. Good luck.